# MySql Remove All Substrings that Match Table Values

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a VARCHAR variable and I would like to remove all substrings that match a column in a table. So far I have built a query that will return all rows that are a substring of my variable, using the following query:

```
SET @myval = '%For Her, Shoes,, Sizes 14-24%';

SELECT strReplace
FROM tbl_StringsToReplace
WHERE @myval LIKE CONCAT('%', strReplace, '%');
```

But I am having trouble writing a REPLACE query that will replace multiple values. I am trying to write something like the following:

```
SET @myval = REPLACE((SELECT strReplace
                    FROM tbl_StringsToReplace
                    WHERE @myval LIKE CONCAT('%', strReplace, '%')), '', @myval);
```

But I am getting the error:

Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

I would love to achieve this in pure SQL. Euther way, any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide your table tbl_StringsToReplace definition and some sample data ?

Comment: Sure, so tbl_StringsToReplace has one column, strReplace, with values such as 

'Shoes, '
'For Him, '
'For Her, '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SET @myval = '%For Her, Shoes,, Sizes 14-24%';

select val into @myval
from (
  SELECT @myval := replace(@myval, strReplace, '') val
  FROM tbl_StringsToReplace 
) r
order by length(val)
limit 1;

select @myval;
```